# Compiling XSD files in Java 11, package javax.xml.bind... does not exist

Tags: java, xsd, java-11

I'm converting a large project from Java 8 to Java 11.  I'm running into a common issue, "package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist".  The project does NOT have an IDE supported in Java 11.

In one module of this project, I resolved this issue by adding the appropriate JAXB and `javax.activation` dependencies to `ivy.xml`. So far so good.

Another module consists solely of `xsd` files.  That module collects the files into a `jar` file, for use by other modules.  This module already had the necessary dependencies in its `ivy.xml` file, but did not compile anything.

The consumer module extracts the `jar` and runs `xjc` on the desired `xsd` file, turning `foo.xsd` into `source/generated/foo.java`.  This source file depends on `javax.xml.bind`.

The consumer's build.xml then calls `javac` on the generated Java file.  This step does not pick up the jaxb dependencies in the consumer's `ivy.xml` file, and so errors out trying to find jaxb.

Should I move the compilation of the generated jaxb classes into the compilation of the main consumer module?  Or something else?

Comment: You need to make sure that the JAXB API jar is included in the classpath when you compile the source code that requires it.